# How to stop a controller without returning any value

Tags: c#

```
public int BackgroundService(string lati, string longi) {
        BackGroundService objBGServices = new BackGroundService();
        return objBGServices.DispatcherTimerSetup(httpClient, lati, longi, UserId);
}
```

but i am getting error like

> Error:
>   Error   83  Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'int'

Comment: What is the return Type of `DispatcherTimerSetup` function ????

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `DispatcherTimerSetup` returns void:

```
public void BackgroundService(string lati, string longi) {
        BackGroundService objBGServices = new BackGroundService();
        objBGServices.DispatcherTimerSetup(httpClient, lati, longi, UserId);
}
```

Remove the return value of `int` and don't return anything: just do the action.

Comment: I Can Do Like this IF i do like this means Breakpoint will come from Dispachtimer function so that I need to stop controller to getting back to execute my Dispacher Functionality Please help me in that how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

**Make it function return type as Void. And don't return anything**.

Based on your Function Return Type:

`DispatcherTimerSetup` returns `void` it means nothing. Where as in `BackgroundService`  function returns `int` value. Thats why you are getting

> Error 83 Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'int'

```
public void DispatcherTimerSetup(HttpClient httpClient, string lati, string longi, string UserId) 
{ 
     dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer(); 
     dispatcherTimer.Tick += dispatcherTimer_Tick; 
     dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1); 
     // TimeSpan for 1 Minute 0 secs 
     if (!dispatcherTimer.IsEnabled) 
     { 
          dispatcherTimer.Start(); 
     }
}

//Wrong return Type
public int BackgroundService(string lati, string longi) {
    BackGroundService objBGServices = new BackGroundService();
    //Problem is Return Type
    return objBGServices.DispatcherTimerSetup(httpClient, lati, longi, UserId);
}

//See the Answer of **Jeroen Vannevel**

public void BackgroundService(string lati, string longi) {
    BackGroundService objBGServices = new BackGroundService();
    objBGServices.DispatcherTimerSetup(httpClient, lati, longi, UserId);
}
```

Comment: I am having this method in controller
void BackgroundService(string lati, string longi)
{}
If I used in above manner means Breakpoint is not hitting the function
 async void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
        {
        }

Comment: Changing `function return type` is not causing the issue I'm sure. Is the function is being called from `dispatcherTimer_Tick` ???